# JSON-LD framing does not embed child elements

Tags: json-ld

I'm trying to frame a json-ld object (here the [solid-terms](https://www.w3.org/ns/solid/terms#) ontology) from a previously flattened json-ld object. I tried to reproduce the example given in the [W3C editors draft](https://w3c.github.io/json-ld-framing/).

Using this frame:

```
{
  "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Ontology",
  "contains": {
    "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class"
  }
}
```

It just results in the ontology itself on the top level without nested `Class` entries.

```
{
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "http://www.w3.org/ns/solid/terms",
      "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Ontology",
      "http://purl.org/dc/terms/issued": {
        "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date",
        "@value": "2015-11-16"
      },
      "http://purl.org/dc/terms/modified": {
        "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date",
        "@value": "2018-01-24"
      },
      "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "Solid terms"
      },
      "https://creativecommons.org/ns#attributionURL": {
        "@id": "http://www.w3.org/ns/solid/terms"
      },
      "https://creativecommons.org/ns#license": {
        "@id": "https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What is wrong with my frame? See the playground example: [JSON-LD Playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-framed&json-ld=%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23Ontology%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fissued%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23date%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%222015-11-16%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fmodified%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23date%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%222018-01-24%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Solid%20terms%22%7D%5D%2C%22https%3A%2F%2Fcreativecommons.org%2Fns%23attributionURL%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22https%3A%2F%2Fcreativecommons.org%2Fns%23license%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fcreativecommons.org%2Fpublicdomain%2Fzero%2F1.0%2F%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Account%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22A%20Solid%20account.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Account%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Inbox%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22A%20resource%20containing%20notifications.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Inbox%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23ListedDocument%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Listed%20Type%20Index%20is%20a%20registry%20of%20resources%20that%20are%20publicly%20discoverable%20by%20outside%20users%20and%20applications.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Listed%20Type%20Index%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Notification%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22A%20notification%20resource.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Notification%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Patch%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22A%20patch%20expresses%20conditional%20modifications%20to%20a%20resource%20that%20has%20an%20RDF-based%20representation.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Patch%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Timeline%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22A%20resource%20containing%20time%20ordered%20items%20and%20sub-containers.%20%20Sub-containers%20may%20be%20desirable%20in%20file%20based%20systems%20to%20split%20the%20timeline%20into%20logical%20components%20e.g.%20%2Fyyyy-mm-dd%2F%20as%20used%20in%20ISO%208061.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Timeline%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23TypeIndex%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22A%20index%20of%20type%20registries%20for%20resources.%20Applications%20can%20register%20the%20RDF%20type%20they%20use%20and%20list%20them%20in%20the%20index%20resource.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Type%20index%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23TypeRegistration%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20registered%20types%20that%20map%20a%20RDF%20classes%2Ftypes%20to%20their%20locations%20using%20either%20%60instance%60%20or%20%60instanceContainer%60%20property.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Type%20Registration%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23UnlistedDocument%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Unlisted%20Type%20Index%20is%20a%20registry%20of%20resources%20that%20are%20private%20to%20the%20user%20and%20their%20apps%2C%20for%20types%20that%20are%20not%20publicly%20discoverable.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Unlisted%20Type%20Index%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23account%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22A%20solid%20account%20belonging%20to%20an%20Agent.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22account%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23deletes%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23FunctionalProperty%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23ObjectProperty%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20triple%20patterns%20this%20patch%20removes%20from%20the%20document.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23domain%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Patch%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22deletes%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23range%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F10%2Fswap%2Flog%23Formula%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23forClass%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22A%20class%20that%20is%20used%20to%20map%20an%20listed%20or%20unlisted%20type%20index.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22registry%20class%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23inbox%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Deprecated%20pointer%20to%20a%20Linked%20Data%20Notifications%20inbox%3B%20please%20use%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fldp%23inbox%20instead.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22inbox%20(deprecated)%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23subPropertyOf%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fldp%23inbox%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23deprecated%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23boolean%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%221%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23equivalentProperty%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fldp%23inbox%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23inserts%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23FunctionalProperty%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23ObjectProperty%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20triple%20patterns%20this%20patch%20adds%20to%20the%20document.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23domain%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Patch%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22inserts%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23range%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F10%2Fswap%2Flog%23Formula%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23instance%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Maps%20a%20type%20to%20an%20individual%20resource%2C%20typically%20an%20index%20or%20a%20directory%20listing%20resource.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22instance%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23instanceContainer%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Maps%20a%20type%20to%20a%20container%20which%20the%20client%20would%20have%20to%20list%20to%20get%20the%20instances%20of%20that%20type.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22instance%20container%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23loginEndpoint%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20login%20URI%20of%20a%20given%20server.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22loginEndpoint%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23logoutEndpoint%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20logout%20URI%20of%20a%20given%20server.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22logoutEndpoint%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23notification%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Notification%20resource%20for%20an%20inbox.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22notification%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23oidcIssuer%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20preferred%20OpenID%20Connect%20issuer%20URI%20for%20a%20given%20Web%20ID.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22oidcIssuer%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23subPropertyOf%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fspecs%2Fconnect%2F1.0%2Fissuer%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23patches%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23ObjectProperty%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20document%20to%20which%20this%20patch%20applies.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23domain%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Patch%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22patches%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23range%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Resource%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23privateTypeIndex%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Points%20to%20an%20unlisted%20type%20index%20resource.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22private%20type%20index%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23range%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23UnlistedDocument%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23publicTypeIndex%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Points%20to%20a%20listed%20type%20index%20resource.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22public%20type%20index%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23range%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23ListedDocument%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23subPropertyOf%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23typeIndex%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23read%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Indicates%20if%20a%20message%20has%20been%20read%20or%20not.%20This%20property%20should%20have%20a%20boolean%20datatype.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23domain%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Frdfs.org%2Fsioc%2Fns%23Post%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22read%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23storageQuota%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23DatatypeProperty%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20quota%20of%20non-volatile%20memory%20that%20is%20available%20for%20the%20account%20(in%20bytes)%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23domain%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Account%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Non-volatile%20memory%20quota%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23storageUsage%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23DatatypeProperty%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20amount%20of%20non-volatile%20memory%20that%20the%20account%20have%20used%20(in%20bytes)%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23domain%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Account%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Non-volatile%20memory%20usage%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23timeline%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Timeline%20for%20a%20given%20resource.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22timeline%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23typeIndex%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Points%20to%20a%20TypeIndex%20resource.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22type%20index%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23range%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23TypeIndex%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23where%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23FunctionalProperty%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23ObjectProperty%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20conditions%20the%20document%20and%20the%20inserted%20and%20deleted%20triple%20patterns%20need%20to%20satisfy%20in%20order%20for%20the%20patch%20to%20be%20applied.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23domain%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Patch%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22where%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23range%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F10%2Fswap%2Flog%23Formula%22%7D%5D%7D%5D&frame=%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23Ontology%22%2C%22contains%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%7D%7D&context=%7B%7D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your frame doesn't specify a @context and therefore `contains` does not have any semantic meaning.

A class is related to the ontology by `http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#isDefinedBy`. So if you want to have a document with Ontology on top level, and all classes defined by it nested via "contains" keyword, you have to use this frame:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#",
    "rdfs": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#",
    "contains": {
      "@reverse": "rdfs:isDefinedBy"
    }
  },
  "@type": "Ontology",
  "contains": {}
}
```

[Permalink to the playground showing this in action](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-framed&json-ld=%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23Ontology%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fissued%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23date%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%222015-11-16%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fmodified%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23date%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%222018-01-24%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Solid%20terms%22%7D%5D%2C%22https%3A%2F%2Fcreativecommons.org%2Fns%23attributionURL%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22https%3A%2F%2Fcreativecommons.org%2Fns%23license%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fcreativecommons.org%2Fpublicdomain%2Fzero%2F1.0%2F%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Account%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22A%20Solid%20account.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Account%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Inbox%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22A%20resource%20containing%20notifications.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Inbox%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23ListedDocument%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Listed%20Type%20Index%20is%20a%20registry%20of%20resources%20that%20are%20publicly%20discoverable%20by%20outside%20users%20and%20applications.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Listed%20Type%20Index%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Notification%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22A%20notification%20resource.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Notification%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Patch%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22A%20patch%20expresses%20conditional%20modifications%20to%20a%20resource%20that%20has%20an%20RDF-based%20representation.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Patch%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Timeline%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22A%20resource%20containing%20time%20ordered%20items%20and%20sub-containers.%20%20Sub-containers%20may%20be%20desirable%20in%20file%20based%20systems%20to%20split%20the%20timeline%20into%20logical%20components%20e.g.%20%2Fyyyy-mm-dd%2F%20as%20used%20in%20ISO%208061.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Timeline%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23TypeIndex%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22A%20index%20of%20type%20registries%20for%20resources.%20Applications%20can%20register%20the%20RDF%20type%20they%20use%20and%20list%20them%20in%20the%20index%20resource.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Type%20index%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23TypeRegistration%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20registered%20types%20that%20map%20a%20RDF%20classes%2Ftypes%20to%20their%20locations%20using%20either%20%60instance%60%20or%20%60instanceContainer%60%20property.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Type%20Registration%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23UnlistedDocument%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Unlisted%20Type%20Index%20is%20a%20registry%20of%20resources%20that%20are%20private%20to%20the%20user%20and%20their%20apps%2C%20for%20types%20that%20are%20not%20publicly%20discoverable.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Unlisted%20Type%20Index%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23account%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22A%20solid%20account%20belonging%20to%20an%20Agent.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22account%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23deletes%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23FunctionalProperty%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23ObjectProperty%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20triple%20patterns%20this%20patch%20removes%20from%20the%20document.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23domain%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Patch%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22deletes%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23range%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F10%2Fswap%2Flog%23Formula%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23forClass%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22A%20class%20that%20is%20used%20to%20map%20an%20listed%20or%20unlisted%20type%20index.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22registry%20class%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23inbox%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Deprecated%20pointer%20to%20a%20Linked%20Data%20Notifications%20inbox%3B%20please%20use%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fldp%23inbox%20instead.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22inbox%20(deprecated)%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23subPropertyOf%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fldp%23inbox%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23deprecated%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23boolean%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%221%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23equivalentProperty%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fldp%23inbox%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23inserts%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23FunctionalProperty%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23ObjectProperty%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20triple%20patterns%20this%20patch%20adds%20to%20the%20document.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23domain%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Patch%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22inserts%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23range%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F10%2Fswap%2Flog%23Formula%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23instance%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Maps%20a%20type%20to%20an%20individual%20resource%2C%20typically%20an%20index%20or%20a%20directory%20listing%20resource.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22instance%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23instanceContainer%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Maps%20a%20type%20to%20a%20container%20which%20the%20client%20would%20have%20to%20list%20to%20get%20the%20instances%20of%20that%20type.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22instance%20container%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23loginEndpoint%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20login%20URI%20of%20a%20given%20server.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22loginEndpoint%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23logoutEndpoint%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20logout%20URI%20of%20a%20given%20server.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22logoutEndpoint%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23notification%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Notification%20resource%20for%20an%20inbox.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22notification%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23oidcIssuer%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20preferred%20OpenID%20Connect%20issuer%20URI%20for%20a%20given%20Web%20ID.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22oidcIssuer%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23subPropertyOf%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fspecs%2Fconnect%2F1.0%2Fissuer%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23patches%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23ObjectProperty%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20document%20to%20which%20this%20patch%20applies.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23domain%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Patch%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22patches%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23range%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Resource%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23privateTypeIndex%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Points%20to%20an%20unlisted%20type%20index%20resource.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22private%20type%20index%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23range%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23UnlistedDocument%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23publicTypeIndex%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Points%20to%20a%20listed%20type%20index%20resource.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22public%20type%20index%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23range%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23ListedDocument%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23subPropertyOf%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23typeIndex%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23read%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Indicates%20if%20a%20message%20has%20been%20read%20or%20not.%20This%20property%20should%20have%20a%20boolean%20datatype.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23domain%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Frdfs.org%2Fsioc%2Fns%23Post%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22read%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23storageQuota%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23DatatypeProperty%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20quota%20of%20non-volatile%20memory%20that%20is%20available%20for%20the%20account%20(in%20bytes)%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23domain%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Account%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Non-volatile%20memory%20quota%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23storageUsage%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23DatatypeProperty%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20amount%20of%20non-volatile%20memory%20that%20the%20account%20have%20used%20(in%20bytes)%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23domain%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Account%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Non-volatile%20memory%20usage%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23timeline%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Timeline%20for%20a%20given%20resource.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22timeline%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23typeIndex%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22Points%20to%20a%20TypeIndex%20resource.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22type%20index%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23range%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23TypeIndex%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23where%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23Property%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23FunctionalProperty%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23ObjectProperty%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23comment%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22The%20conditions%20the%20document%20and%20the%20inserted%20and%20deleted%20triple%20patterns%20need%20to%20satisfy%20in%20order%20for%20the%20patch%20to%20be%20applied.%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23domain%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%23Patch%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22where%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23range%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F10%2Fswap%2Flog%23Formula%22%7D%5D%7D%5D&frame=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40vocab%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%22%2C%22rdfs%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%22%2C%22contains%22%3A%7B%22%40reverse%22%3A%22rdfs%3AisDefinedBy%22%7D%7D%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22Ontology%22%2C%22contains%22%3A%7B%7D%7D&context=%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23Class%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23isDefinedBy%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fsolid%2Fterms%22%7D).